# JavaFX how to parse HTML String into HTML Element?

Tags: java, html, javafx

I wrote a method to insert a div with text passed as parameter.
And then I noticed I need to add various HTML content into that div. Current method works on these basic 5 lines of instruction:

```
//engine is the WebEngine object of some WebView object
Node html = engine.getDocument().getChildNodes().item(0);
Node body = html.getChildNodes().item(1);
Element e = engine.getDocument().createElement("div");
e.setTextContent(msg);
body.appendChild(e);
```

So here comes my question. Is there a way of parsing some HTML content into an Element object, so I can append that element to the document?
Example HTML String: `<b>SomeText</b>`

Comment: You can see if [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) has what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with Javascript! I could append any HTML data with JS.
Example:

```
engine.executeScript("document.body.innerHTML += '<div><b>SomeText</b></div>' ");
```

Answer (score -1):

I recently created such a tool, I hope it helps a lot
https://github.com/graycatdeveloper/JavaFXHtmlText